# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting using MySQL and Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am importing text file to mysql database by using python script, but I get a weird error and search for it over internet but could'nt find exact solution. I want to create columns and some columns will store data in decimal with negative sign like this

```
Alarmdata    fuAlarm
-1585.4       -35.3
-343.32       -54.3
```

I get the following error

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near '                 Alarmdata,
fuel_in_l DECIMAL(5,2), fuAlarm DECIMAL(4,3),        ' at line 1")
```

I solved this issue by giving data type to blank data but now I am facing this error.

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My code is below

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost' , 'root' , 'kami' , 'tempdat')

cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Datatmp (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY     AUTO_INCREMENT, \
            timestamp INT(12), pomode INT(3), modeAlarm INT(3), \
            temperature_C DECIMAL(2,1), temperatureAlarm INT(3), \
            switch INT(3), Powerswitch INT(3), SIM_dollar INT , \
            Alarmdata INT, fuel_in_l DECIMAL(5,2), fuAlarm DECIMAL(4,3), \
            next_maint DECIMAL(5,2), next_maintenanceAlarm INT(2) )');

con.commit()             

file = open('//home/mysql/kami.txt', 'rb')
creader = csv.reader(txtfile.readlines()[3:], delimiter='\t')

for t in creader:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Datatmp(timestamp, pomode, modeAlarm,\
                    temperature_C, temperatureAlarm, \
                    switch, Powerswitch, SIM_dollar, \
                    Alarmdata, fuel_in_l, fuAlarm \   
                    next_maint,  next_maintenanceAlarm)\
                    Values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,NULL,NULL,%s,%s,%s,\
                    %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', t) 

file.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Type error mean that I didn't pass enough %s , but I passed the same number and it should not display this error. I am new to MySQL and python as well, so I didn't solve.

Comment: in your table definition you have no data type for Alarmdata

Comment: @Niagaradad Yes that where I get no clue. if the column is in table but had no data , just blank. then what data type I should display? NULL or  INT?  and second if i had value like -152.43  , how can I assign data type of this? .  if any tip, I will really thankful . I spend my whole day on it.

Comment: OP - a community wiki was added as an answer to your last statement but does not make sense. Python's *Nones* are translated as *Nulls* in MySQL. Also, your append query is missing a comma and is passing in too many placeholders for listed fields. Future readers may be interested in what you found out. Please answer fully your own question with example code adjustment.

Comment: I provide my answer with code example and correct answer. I hope it will help people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import MySQLdb as mdb


con = mdb.connect('localhost' , 'root' , 'kami' , 'tempdat')

cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE Datatmp (timestamp INT(12), pomode INT(3), \
            modeAlarm INT(3), temperature_C DECIMAL(2,1),temperatureAlarm INT(3), \
            switch INT(3), Powerswitch INT(3),SIM_dollar INT(3), \
            Alarmdata INT(5),fuel_in_l DECIMAL(5,2), fuAlarm DECIMAL(4,3), \
            next_maint DECIMAL(5,2), next_maintenanceAlarm INT(2))');




con.commit()             

file = open('//home/mysql/kami.txt', 'rb')
creader = csv.reader(txtfile.readlines()[3:], delimiter='\t')



# now insert values in database
i = 0;

# read and store the values in database and also replace empty data 

for t in creader:
    print t
    for idx, v in enumerate(t):
        if v == ' ':
            t[idx] = None                   
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Data_121_RAPI_txt VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, \
                %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s)', t)                
 i = i + 1



file.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Here I face two problems. 1)  if there are empty columns like Alarmdata, I still need to pass datatype and here I pass INT datatype so this error can easily be removed.

```
 2)   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Here the problem was that I pass NULL in cursor.execute and it gives error, so I make code which turn every empty space and write there None. and in palceholder I didn't provide NULL but simply normal palceholder,  and also providing correct number of placeholders , the issue is solved.

I hope it will help people.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, INT datatype can have the value ranges from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`. So you can simply put the datatype INT there. Rest everything will be by taken care by MySQL.

Comment: you mean to assign -153.33 I will give datatype of INT?   because for the blank data I solve by assigning INT datatype. Although i get a new error. TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
 but I will solve it soon. Actual problem is with assigning data type to -153.33 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved this problem. The issue is that blank spaces are read by Python if we convert them to type of None.